# Error: Timeout waiting for Codecov Default to start while setting up codecov self-hosted repo

Tags: docker, docker-compose, codecov

I am trying codecov self-hosted repo for POC, I am constantly getting this error
self-hosted-gateway-1    | Still waiting for Codecov Default to start ...
self-hosted-gateway-1    | Timeout waiting for Codecov Default to start

All remaining dependent containers are up, not able to find Codecov Default container in codecov docs also, is it renamed? gateway container is up for 30 secs and then it is exiting

I tried with different images of gateway in different distress like ubuntu, centos and in Mac. I want gateway container to be up so that I can access UI, gateway container is up for 30 sec and then it is exiting